# Is it possible to pass a F# function by Reflection?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to pass a F# function by Reflection?

```
(*in module A*)
type Foo() =
    static member bar n = {1..n}

let functionUsingFoobar (x:(int -> #('a seq)) n =
    let z = BarFoo.ofSeq (x n)
    z.count

(* in module B
here is where I want to pass Foo.bar by reflection*)
let y = functionUsingFoobar Foo.bar 1000
```

I cannot invoke the member without the args parameter, so partial function application through InvokeMember cannot work.

```
let foo = new Foo()
let z = foo.GetType().InvokeMember("bar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, foo, [|1000|])
(*tried null, [||], [|null|] for args parameter*)
```

I'm out of ideas how to pass the function by reflection

Comment: I don't understand how your second code sample connects to the first - what's seqIntAsc?

Comment: Oops--thanks for pointing that out. Corrected to "bar". The second code sample invokes the "bar" member of type Foo, which is not what I want to do. I suspect passing the function like a partial function is not possible with reflection.

Comment: What is the actual _problem_? Do you get a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: I want to pass the function Foo.bar to "functionUsingFoobar" in order to be executed within functionUsingFoobar. But, I want to select Foo.bar by means of reflection (so that I could choose any other function with the same signature as Foo.bar using reflection and pass it instead).

I investigated attempting to use InvokeMember somehow spoofing the args parameter as null or empty array in order to create a partial function, but "null" does not build and empty array fails at runtime (if I remember right). So my conclusion is you cannot pass a partial function by reflection using InvokeMember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `GetMethod` returns a `MethodInfo`, but you need an F# function value.  The easiest way to overcome this mismatch is probably to use `CreateDelegate` to create a .NET delegate from the method, and then treat the `Invoke` method as a function value of the correct type:

```
let d = 
    typeof<Foo>.GetMethod("bar").CreateDelegate(typeof<System.Func<int,seq<int>>>) 
    :?> System.Func<int,seq<int>>
functionUsingFooBar d.Invoke 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what I think you want, it works just fine

```
type Foo() =
    static member bar n = {1..n}

let functionUsingFoobar (x:(int -> #('a seq))) n =
    (x n) |> Seq.length

let y = functionUsingFoobar Foo.bar 1000
let foo = new Foo()
let z = fun t -> foo.GetType().InvokeMember("bar", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, foo, [|t|])
```

Comment: No, that "invokes", i.e. executes, Foo.bar. I want to pass the function Foo.bar to the function "functionUsingFoobar" in order to be executed within functionUsingFoobar. But, I want to select Foo.bar by means of reflection (so that I could choose any other function with the same signature as Foo.bar using reflection and pass it instead).